# Почему меняются местами аргументы при использовании функции super()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Вопрос формулировал, наверное,  двое суток, толком так и не знаю как спросить.
Долго и упорно гуглил, но не понял...
Есть код. И я пытаюсь разобрать его пошагово. [ссылка на PythonTutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=class%20Worker%3A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20__init__%28self,%20name,%20surname,%20position%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.name%20%3D%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.surname%20%3D%20surname%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.position%20%3D%20position%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self._income%20%3D%20%7B%27wage%27%3A3000,%20%27bonus%27%3A1000%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0Aclass%20Position%28Worker%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20__init__%28self,%20name,%20surname,%20position%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super%28%29.__init__%28surname,%20name,%20position%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20def%20get_full_name%28self%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%27%7B%7D%20%7B%7D%27.format%28self.name,%20self.surname%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20def%20get_total_income%28self%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20self._income%5B%27wage%27%5D%20%2B%20self._income%5B%27bonus%27%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%0Apos%20%3D%20Position%28%27Bilbo%27,%20%27Baggins%27,%20%27Treasure%20Hunter%27%29%0A%0Aprint%28pos.get_full_name%28%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=10&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)
Суть в том, что понимаю в какой момент, но не понимаю почему, из-за строки `super().__init__(surname, name, position)` аргументы "меняются местами" и на выходе вместо `Bilbo Baggins` получается `Baggins Bilbo`. Я понимаю причину, происходит это из-за того, что  у меня в `super().__init__(surname, name, position)` `surname` и `name` поменяны местами относительно инициализатора дочернего класса`def __init__(self, name, surname, position):`
Но я не понимаю почему это происходит. Это ведь не именованные аргументы. Я не совсем понимаю очевидно как работает `super()`. Я полагал, что важен порядок, т.е.  в `surname super'а` подаётся `name` из `def __init__(self, name, surname, position)`, но он же всё-равно стоит на первом месте...

Дико извиняюсь за такой скомканый вопрос, надеюсь кто-нибудь всё-таки поймёт.

```
class Worker:
    def __init__(self, name, surname, position):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.position = position
        self._income = {'wage':3000, 'bonus':1000}
        
class Position(Worker):
    def __init__(self, name, surname, position):
        super().__init__(surname, name, position)
        
    def get_full_name(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.name, self.surname)
    
    def get_total_income(self):
        return self._income['wage'] + self._income['bonus']
    
    
pos = Position('Bilbo', 'Baggins', 'Treasure Hunter')

print(pos.get_full_name())
```

Comment: А почему не `super().__init__(name, surname, position)`? И так как это повторяет родительский конструктор, то дочерний конструктор вообще можно не писать.

Comment: @u_mulder Случайно написал, а теперь стало интересно просто. Про конструктор я в курсе, но вопрос не в этом.

Comment: name "Bilbo" идет в surname родительского класса, surname "Baggins" идет в name родительского класса. Все так, как и описано вами же в вопросе. Совершенно непонятно, что именно вам непонятно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае вы передаете параметры не как именованные, а как позиционные, поэтому нужно передавать параметры именно в том порядке, в каком они у вас перечислены в `__init__` родительского класса.

Имена переменных, значения которых вы передаете в `__init__` никак не связаны с именами параметров `__init__` родительского класса. То есть при вызове `super().__init__(surname, name, position)` у вас, например, значение переменной `surname` передается первым параметром, а в `__init__` родительского класса первый параметр - `name`, то есть вместо имени передается фамилия, и т.д.

Если хотите передавать параметры в произвольном порядке, передавайте их как именованные параметры:

```
super().__init__(surname=surname, name=name, position=position)
```

Тут слева от равно - имя параметра, справа - имя переменной, значение которой вы передаете.

---

Еще раз по шагам:

- `pos = Position('Bilbo', 'Baggins', 'Treasure Hunter')` - тут вызывается `__init__` класса `Position` (объявление `def __init__(self, name, surname, position)`), в первый параметр (`name`) попадает `'Bilbo'`, во второй (`surname`) - `'Baggins'`
- `super().__init__(surname, name, position)` - тут вызывается `__init__` класса `Worker` (объявление `def __init__(self, name, surname, position)`), в первый параметр (`name`) вы кладете значение из переменной `surname` (`'Baggins'`), во второй (`surname`) - значение из переменной `name` (`'Bilbo'`)

Ответ на вопрос "Почему меняются местами аргументы" - потому что вы сами их поменяли местами.

Comment: То, что они позиционные как раз я понимаю, я вот к сожалению понять не могу вот какой момент в `super().__init__(surname, name, position)` я в `surname` же подаю Bilbo, дальше этот `surname` будучи позиционными "становится"  name'ом родительского `__init__` и в свою очередь становится `self.name` . Разве не так?

Comment: @TobaSko вот тут `Position('Bilbo', 'Baggins', 'Treasure Hunter')` вы в `__init__` класса Position передаете в name - 'Bilbo', в surname - 'Baggins'. А в родительский `__init__` передаете в противоположном порядке, в первый параметр (name) кладете surname, во второй (surname) - name.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 4):

В данном случае вызов через `super()` ничем не отличается от вызова обычной функции, позиционные аргументы передаются абсолютно одинаково при любых вызовах:

```py
def super_init(name, surname):
    print('{} {}'.format(name, surname))

def the_init(name, surname):
    super_init(surname, name)

super_init('Bilbo', 'Baggins') # Bilbo Baggins
the_init  ('Bilbo', 'Baggins') # Baggins Bilbo
```

Comment: так вот я этого и не могу понять =\ По идее важен порядок. Тогда почему если в     `super().__init__(surname, name, position)`   мы подаём последовательно    'Bilbo', 'Baggins', 'Treasure Hunter'    ,то они меняются. местами. Ваш пример я понял, но вот к super никак его не могу применить.

Comment: @TobaSko а с чего вы взяли, что подаёте их именно в таком порядке?

Comment: потому что я их так подавал в качестве аргументов экземпляра класса. Или я чего-то не понимаю...

Comment: @TobaSko а причём тут аргументы экземпляра класса? Вы вызвали `super().__init__` с параметрами `'Baggins', 'Bilbo','Treasure Hunter'`